# React function component Callback give not a function error

Tags: reactjs, callback

What is wrong with this function

```
  function Test({ setColor }) {
   return (
    <div>
     <h1>Test</h1>
     <button onClick={(e) => setColor('black')}>Set Color</button>
     </div>
     );
  }

 export default Test;
```

to give me this error

> Test.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: setColor is not a function
> at onClick (Test.js:18:1)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVsvn.png)

Comment: can you show how you are passing `setColor` prop to `Test` component ?

Answer (score 2):

This error happens because you don't provide any props to your `Test` component. So, your `setColor` is `undefined` and when you want to call `setColor` you receive an error.

There you have two possible solutions:

1. Provide default value for `setColor` prop:

```
function Test({ setColor = () => {} }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <button onClick={(e) => setColor("black")}>Set Color</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

2. Provide a prop for your component:

```
export default function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Test setColor={setColor} />
      <p>Your color is: {color}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-cache-1pejip?file=/src/App.js) for more details